# How to Return data from a function inside a polymer dom-module?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I'm new to polymer so here I'm trying to return some simple data with a function inside a polymer dom-module where:

```
Username and date: <p>{{test()}}</p>
```

should display a name and a date, but actually is returning nothing. Anything wrong in my code? I also used the debugger in chrome and the object is actually there when return is called.

```
<dom-module id="user-list-module">
  <template>
      <paper-material elevation="1">
        Username and date: <p>{{test()}}</p>
      </paper-material>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      Polymer({
        is: 'user-list-module',
        properties: {
            username: String,
            joined: Date,
        },
        test: function () {
          this.username = '';
          this.joined = '';
          var fb = new Firebase('https://blistering-torch-8317.firebaseio.com/users/public/');
          fb.on('value', function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
              var key = childSnapshot.key();
              var childData = childSnapshot.val();
              this.username = childData.username;
              this.joined = childData.date.split(' ').slice(0, 4).join(' ');
              return this.username + ' ' + this.joined;
            });
          })
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

[image]

Comment: As an aside, is there a reason you're wrapping `Polymer({});` in an anonymous function? I haven't seen this advised in any of the docs or examples.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know why it's wrapped on an anonymous function did remove it, but no result so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in the original code: because the `on` method is async, there's no way for your `test` method to return a value. By the time your callback is invoked, `test` has already returned.

```
Username and date: <p><span>{{combine(firstname, joined)}}</span></p>
```

Where `combine` is a function like this:

```
combine: function(first, date) {
  return first + ' ' + date;
}
```

Or without the function:

```
Username and date: <p><span>{{firstname}}</span> <span>{{joined}}</span></p>
```

Then kick off your existing `test` method from `ready`.

```
ready: function() {
  this.test();
}
```

Comment: Note: as of Polymer 1.2.4, you no longer need a computed binding or the `<span>` tags for simple string interpolation like this. Now you can just use:

`Username and date: <p>{firstname}} {{joined}}</p>`

Answer (score 2):

function test() doesn't return anything (it's the 'value' event handler that is returning something).

I suggest you switch to using the firebase polymer elements :

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element?active=firebase-collection

or move the firebase code you have in 'test()' to a 'ready()' function, and have 'test()' simply as "return this.username + ' ' + this.joined;", if that corresponds with your intent.

TBH, it's not too clear exactly what you want since snapshot seems to be a collection (ie forEach() implies *more than one* username+joined) but your html seems to only want a single username+joined, and the properties declaration reflects that too - perhaps you also want to consider having a dom-repeat template? Hrm, perhaps you only want the last value of the snapshot to be relevant. It's a little confusing, sorry.

Comment: Yeah It look a bit weird the forEach loop but that was just a test to see If test() was returning any data

Answer (score 0):

All data binding in the `<template>` needs wrapped in a `<span>`. Like this:

```
Username and date: <p><span>{{test()}}</span></p>
```

Comment: Haven't read anything like that in the documentation. Anyway I did use span for a test by the result is the same, nothing returned.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a response from Firebase? Try returning a simple string from your `test` method. It should work.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot the object in chrome debugger is returned and the right value is assigned to this.username & this.joined, but  nothing is returned. If I remove the firebase call and  assign this.username = 'John' and this.joined = '7 Oct 2015', it is working

Comment: IINM, this answer is incorrect. The bindings just have to be the only text inside an element - so <p>{{test()}}</p> is fine, but <p>something {{test()}}</p> is not. It doesn't have to be a <span>.